# Comparing Images with Python

Tags: python, image

I want to compare two different product listings from two completely different websites(for example eBay and Amazon) using their images in order to find out whether or not the images/product is the same. What is the best way to compare the images considering that images come in different sizes on different websites. I don't want the comparison to be affected because of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

2 libraries you might want to consider are OpenCV or skimage.

These articles give implementation examples that will be helpful:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-compare-two-images-using-opencv-python-6cb2af2b1095

If you run into coding problems, happy to try to help there.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!!